# Is it possible to use target row to initialize a Spark UDAF?

Tags: python, scala, pandas, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a problem that I am trying to solve in Spark by defining my own UDAF by trying to mimic the recommendations given [here](https://www.jowanza.com/blog/a-gentle-intro-to-udafs-in-apache-spark) and [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-UserDefinedAggregateFunction.html). My eventual goal is to apply a series of complex bit-shifting and bit-wise boolean manipulations to a sequence of integers within a given window.

I am having issues since my use-case is on a fairly large dataset (~100million rows, for which I need to perform 6 such bit-wise manipulations on groups ranging from 2-7 elements long), and am therefore trying to implement this in scala. Problem is that I'm brand new to scala (my primary language being python), and while scala itself doesn't seem that difficult, the combination of both a new language plus specifics of the UDAF class itself as applied to `window`s is leaving me a little stumped.

## Explaining the logic by example in python/pandas

To make the question more concrete, consider a **`pandas`** `DataFrame`:

```
keep = list(range(30))
for num in (3, 5, 11, 16, 22, 24):
    keep.pop(num)
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': 'A',
    'date': pd.date_range('2018-06-01', '2018-06-30')[keep],
    'num': np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=30)[keep]
})
```

Which produces:

```
   id       date  num
0   A 2018-06-01    9
1   A 2018-06-02   25
2   A 2018-06-03   68
3   A 2018-06-05   80
4   A 2018-06-06   49
5   A 2018-06-08   95
6   A 2018-06-09   53
7   A 2018-06-10   99
8   A 2018-06-11   54
9   A 2018-06-12   67
10  A 2018-06-13   99
11  A 2018-06-15   35
12  A 2018-06-16   25
13  A 2018-06-17   16
14  A 2018-06-18   61
15  A 2018-06-19   59
16  A 2018-06-21   10
17  A 2018-06-22   94
18  A 2018-06-23   87
19  A 2018-06-24    3
20  A 2018-06-25   28
21  A 2018-06-26    5
22  A 2018-06-28    2
23  A 2018-06-29   14
```

What I would like to be able to do is, **relative to the current row**, find the number of days, then perform some bit-wise manipulations based on that value. To demonstrate, staying in pandas (I will have to do a full outer join then filter to demonstrate):

```
exp_df = df[['id', 'date']].merge(df, on='id') \ # full outer join on 'id'
                           .assign(days_diff = lambda df: (df['date_y'] - df['date_x']).dt.days) \ # number of days since my date of interest
                           .mask(lambda df: (df['days_diff'] > 3) | (df['days_diff'] < 0)) \ # nulls rows where days_diff isn't between 0 and 3
                           .dropna() \ # then filters the rows
                           .drop('date_y', axis='columns') \
                           .rename({'date_x': 'date', 'num': 'nums'}, axis='columns') \
                           .reset_index(drop=True)
exp_df[['nums', 'days_diff']] = exp_df[['nums', 'days_diff']].astype('int')
```

Now I perform my bit-wise shifting and other logic:

```
# Extra values to add after bit-wise shifting (1 for shift of 1, 3 for shift of 2 ...)
additions = {val: sum(2**power for power in range(val)) for val in exp_df['days_diff'].unique()}
exp_df['shifted'] = np.left_shift(exp_df['nums'].values, exp_df['days_diff'].values) \
                    + exp_df['days_diff'].apply(lambda val: additions[val])
```

After all this, `exp_df` looks like the following (first 10 rows):

```
  id       date  nums  days_diff  shifted
0  A 2018-06-01     9          0        9
1  A 2018-06-01    25          1       51
2  A 2018-06-01    68          2      275
3  A 2018-06-02    25          0       25
4  A 2018-06-02    68          1      137
5  A 2018-06-02    80          3      647
6  A 2018-06-03    68          0       68
7  A 2018-06-03    80          2      323
8  A 2018-06-03    49          3      399
9  A 2018-06-05    80          0       80
```

Now I can aggregate:

```
exp_df.groupby('date')['shifted'].agg(lambda group_vals: np.bitwise_and.reduce(group_vals.values)
```

And the final result looks like the following (if I join back to the original `DataFrame`:

```
   id       date  num  shifted
0   A 2018-06-01    9        1
1   A 2018-06-02   25        1
2   A 2018-06-03   68        0
3   A 2018-06-05   80       64
4   A 2018-06-06   49       33
5   A 2018-06-08   95        3
6   A 2018-06-09   53        1
7   A 2018-06-10   99        1
8   A 2018-06-11   54        6
9   A 2018-06-12   67        3
10  A 2018-06-13   99        3
11  A 2018-06-15   35        3
12  A 2018-06-16   25        1
13  A 2018-06-17   16        0
14  A 2018-06-18   61       21
15  A 2018-06-19   59       35
16  A 2018-06-21   10        8
17  A 2018-06-22   94        6
18  A 2018-06-23   87        3
19  A 2018-06-24    3        1
20  A 2018-06-25   28        0
21  A 2018-06-26    5        1
22  A 2018-06-28    2        0
23  A 2018-06-29   14       14
```

## Back to the question

Ok, now that I've demonstrated my logic, I realize that I can essentially do the same thing in Spark - performing a full outer join of the DataFrame on itself, then filtering and aggregating.

What I want to know is if I can *avoid* performing a full join, and instead create my own UDAF to perform this aggregation over a window function, using the target row as an input. Basically, I need to create the equivalent of the `"days_diff"` column in order to perform my required logic, which means comparing the target date to each of the other dates within my specified window. Is this even possible?

Also, am I even justified in worrying about using a self-join? I know that spark does all of its processing lazily, so it's very possible that I wouldn't need to worry . Should I expect the performance to be similar if I were to do all of this using a self join versus my imaginary UDAF applied over a window? The logic is more sequential and easier to follow using the join-filter-aggregate method, which is a clear advantage.

One thing to know is that I will be performing this logic on **multiple** windows. In principle, I could `cache` the *largest* version of the filtered DataFrame after the join, then use that for subsequent calculations.